# Matrix Algebra - $A^m=0$, prove that $I_n+A$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am given a square $n\times n$ matrix $A$ over an arbitrary field. For some natural number $m$ I have that $A^m = 0_V$. I want to prove that $I_n + A$ is invertible. I am not sure if my method covers all possibilities of what $A$ could be.

My method:

Letting $Q = I_n + A$. Then applying $A$, $m - 1$ times i.e. pre/post-multiplying by $A^{m-1}$ and re-arranging I get:

$$QA^{m-1} - A^m = A^{m-1}$$

Then simplifying

$$QA^{m-1} = A^{m-1}$$

Which then implies that $(Q-I_n)A^{m-1}=0_V$. I claim that this implies that $Q = I_n$ or $A^{m-1}  = 0_V$ both of which imply $A = 0_V$ the latter by the above method. Which in turn show the invertibility of $Q$.

However it feels as if I am disregarding the possibility that $ZA^{m-1} = 0_V$ where $Z = Q-I_n$  and $Z$ and $A^{m-1}$ are both non-zero. Is this the case?

I also know I can prove invertibility by showing the matrix can be reduced to the identity matrix but using matrix algebra is far more approachable.

Comment: Is $m\geq 1$? Else, if your field is $\mathbb Z_2$, you might have a problem.

Comment: @Zuy $m \ge 1$ yes.

Comment: Hint: Use $(1-A)(1+A+\dots+A^k)=1-A^{k+1}$ for fitting $k\in\mathbb N$ (where $1$ is the identity matrix).

Comment: @Zuy I see, I have it now - just wondering if there is any other method which doesn't use the "trick"?

Comment: You could show that $A^m = 0$ implies that the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$, and then work out that this implies that $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $A+I$, and hence $A+I$ is invertible.